# Prove that det $A$ = det $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know some ways to prove this, but now I'm looking for another one using this:

$\det A=\det A^T$

$\det\left(\frac{\ A+A^T}{2} +\frac{\ A-A^T}{2}\right)= \det \left(\frac{\ A^T+A}{2} +\frac{\ A^T-A}{2}\right)$

So I have something like:

$\det(B+C) = \det(B-C)$ where $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is skew-symmetric.

Can it be finished somehow using this?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the approach you want. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $\det A=\sum_\sigma\epsilon_\sigma\prod_{i=1}^nA_{i\sigma(i)}$ is a sum over all permutations $\sigma$ of $1,\,2,\,\cdots,\,n$, where the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_\sigma=\pm 1$ is the permutation parity of $\sigma$. Similarly, $\det A^T=\sum_\sigma\epsilon_\sigma\prod_{i=1}^nA_{\sigma(i)i}$. Since each permutation has an inverse of the same parity, $\det A=\det A^T$.